# PHP Fatal error: Class 'library\App\App_TestClass' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\dev.gamenomad.com\application\controllers\ParticipantController.php

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new to zend framework. I'm trying to write a custom class. Here is The code:

```
<?php
namespace library\App;

class App_TestClass {
    private $name;
    function __construct(){
        $this->name = 'My name is Test Class';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

?>
```

This class is located in `library/App` folder. I have also added this code to Bootstrap.php file:

```
public function _initAutoload()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'  => 'library',
            'namespace' => 'App'));     
}
```

When I instantiate this class in ParticipantController.php I get this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'library\App\App_TestClass' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\dev.gamenomad.com\application\controllers\ParticipantController.php`
I know this question has been asked before. But I couldn't solve my problem. Any help is appreciated in adveance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are mixing namespace with path in class name.

For ZF1 use just:

> class App_TestClass {

delete - namespace library\App;

and change to:

> $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
>               'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH .'library',
>               'namespace' => 'App_'));

Comment: APPLICATION_PATH refers to application directory. But library folder is in the root directory of my application. I mean library and application are sibling. Is there a variable that refers to the root of zend framework?